# How To Parse a String (From a different Table) in Hive (Hadoop) And Load It To a Different Table

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, hive, bigdata

I have this Table as an Input:

```
Table Name:Deals
Columns: Doc_id(BIGINT),Nv_Pairs_Feed(STRING),Nv_Pairs_Category(STRING)
For Example:
Doc_id: 4997143658422483637
Nv_Pairs_Feed: "TYPE:Wiper Blade;CONDITION:New;CATEGORY:Auto Parts and Accessories;STOCK_AVAILABILITY:Y;ORIGINAL_PRICE:0.00"
Nv_Pairs_Category: "Condition:New;Store:PartsGeek.com;"
```

I am trying to parse Fields: "Nv_Pairs_Feed" & "Nv_Pairs_Category" and extract their N:V Pairs (each pair is Divided by ';', and each Name and Value are divided with ':').
My goal is to insert each N:V as a Row in this table:

```
Doc_id | Name | Value | Source_Field
```

Example for desired Result:

```
4997143658422483637 | Condition | New | Nv_Pairs_Category
4997143658422483637 | Store     | PartsGeek.com | Nv_Pairs_Category
4997143658422483637 | TYPE | Wiper Blade | Nv_Pairs_Feed
4997143658422483637 | CONDITION | New | Nv_Pairs_Feed
4997143658422483637 | CATEGORY | Auto Parts and Accessories | Nv_Pairs_Feed
4997143658422483637 | STOCK_AVAILABILITY | Y | Nv_Pairs_Feed
4997143658422483637 | ORIGINAL_PRICE | 0.00 | Nv_Pairs_Feed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the strings to a map using the standard Hive UDF `str_to_map` and then use the Brickhouse UDF ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) `map_key_values` , `combine` and `numeric_range` to explode those maps. i.e Something like the following

```
create view deals_map_view as
  select doc_id, 
     map_key_values(
         combine( map_to_str( nv_pairs_feed, ';', ':'),
                  map_to_str( mv_pairs_category, ';', ':'))) as deals_map_key_values
 from deals;


 select
   doc_id,
    array_index( deals_map_key_values, i ).key as name,
    array_index( deals_map_key_values, i ).value as value
   from deals_map_view
   lateral view numeric_range( size( feed_map_key_values) ) i1 as i
```

You can probably do something similar with an `explode_map` UDF

Comment: thank you Jerome for the assistance.  Unfortunately, Combine, Map_Keys_values are not used in my HIVE, and it's not clear how to do so from the Links youv'e added.

Comment: You'll need to install brickhouse in your hive distribution.  Add the jar from our Downloads page https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Downloads , and add it to your $HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH directory, like other external UDFs. You'll also need to source the brickhouse.hql ( https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/resources/brickhouse.hql ) in your script.